# Multi grouping in extjs 5 grid panel

Tags: grouping, extjs5

Is there any way to implement multiple grouping in Extjs 5 grid?

I see some demos for Extjs 4. Can anyone show me one in Extjs 5?

I use Extjs 5.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of box functionality to achieve multiple level grouping in grid.

ExtJS 6 has "Pivot Grid" functionality which may be what you are looking for. 
Example: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/kitchensink/#compact-pivot-grid